# Play music on HomePod for a fixed amount of time without Siri

Tags: macos, music, ipados, homepod, automation

Siri doesn’t work with my voice.  I want to play music on my HomePod for a fixed amount of time

Generally I start it via my iPad but I could start it via my Mac if it would help.  Then I would like the music to stop after an hour (for example).

There does not seem to be any UI to do this.  Setting a timer on the iPad to turn the music off in an hour (or 5 seconds) does nothing when the timer expires.

Comment: "Siri doesn’t work with my voice" You can usually fix that. My partner speaks with 'perfect' pronunciation [RP English] yet Siri does not respond properly because SHE…SPEAKS…TO…IT…LIKE…THIS [the stereotype of an English tourist speaking to a foreigner - loud & halting]. I have what could be termed "a lot of accent" yet I just speak to it in my heavily-accented normal voice & it responds every time.

Comment: @Tetsujin No... my voice doesn't even register.  I've tried using microphones... I've tried lots of stuff.  I wish I could get one of Apple's engineers engaged to see if this could be fixed.  I'm sure there are others with the same issue.